# Once I sample a row from a pandas DataFrame, how can I get a value of one cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` DataFrame and I've successfully sampled a row from it, but one of the problems is that it simply returns another DataFrame. I need to read the returned row and get the value of a particular element of that row.

My `DataFrame` looks like:

```
            Date        Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close     Volume
0     1993-01-29   43.968700   43.968700   43.750000   43.937500   26.836645    1003200
1     1993-02-01   43.968700   44.250000   43.968700   44.250000   27.027504     480500
2     1993-02-02   44.218700   44.375000   44.125000   44.343700   27.084740     201300
3     1993-02-03   44.406200   44.843700   44.375000   44.812500   27.371080     529400
4     1993-02-04   44.968700   45.093700   44.468700   45.000000   27.485609     531500
```

I'm able to sample a row with:

```
start_state = self.market_data.iloc[:-self._num_trading_days_in_episode].sample(1)
```

which ends up looking like:

```
            Date        Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close     Volume
5299  2014-02-13  180.839996  183.199997  180.830002  183.009995  165.017517  100542200
```

Now I need to figure out how to read the value of `Open` from that row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
start_state = self.market_data.iloc[:-self._num_trading_days_in_episode].sample(1)
```

First is possible select by labels by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with get first value of index:

```
open = start_state.loc[start_state.index[0], 'Open']
#faster alternative
#open = start_state.at[start_state.index[0], 'Open']
```

Or by position by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
pos = market_data.columns.get_loc('Open')
open = start_state.iloc[0, pos]
#faster alternative
#open = start_state.iat[0, pos]
```

Or select in numpy array first value by indexing:

```
open = start_state['Open'].values[0]
#pandas 0.24+
#open = start_state['Open'].to_numpy()[0]
```

Or [`Series.item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html) for convert one item `Series` to scalar:

```
open = start_state['Open'].item()
```

Comment: I don't want to ONLY sample the `Open`. I need other values for different things

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that as of pandas 0.24, [`array` is recommended over `values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html).

Answer (score 1):

That simply boils down to

```
self.market_data.Open.iloc[:-self._num_trading_days_in_episode].sample(1).iloc[0]
```

Comment: This returns: `4871    131.710007
Name: Open, dtype: float64`. Whereas I only want the value

Comment: You can get that by putting a `.iloc[0]` at the end; updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Once you sample you can just call the column you want. Either with loc (label) or with iloc (index)

```
start_state = self.market_data.iloc[:-self._num_trading_days_in_episode].sample(1)

start_state.loc[:]['Open']
```

Comment: Do you test it?

Comment: well, not really. I am not sure how this `self` thing work so I simply pulled a row out of the database and then tried to index the elements.

Comment: `self` should be omit in your test.

Comment: yeha, I just noticed that sample() returns a different object than simply slicing the dataframe. I corrected the code accordingly (still not the best solution probably but at least now it works)